# Is there REST API reverse proxy library to inject request headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm setting up a small Python service to act as an REST API reverse proxy, but hoping there's some libraries available to help speed this process up.

Need to be able to run a function to calculate a variable to inject as a request header when the request is proxied through to the backend.

As it stands I have a simpler script to do the function to get the variable and inject it into a Nginx config file and then force a Nginx hot reload via signals, but trying to remove this dependency for what should be a fairly simple task.

Would a good approach be to use falcon as the listener and combine it with another approach to inject and forward requests?

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Been reading https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ as it seems to be the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to someone over at falcon, this is now the accepted answer!

```
import io

import falcon
import requests


class Proxy(object):
    UPSTREAM = 'https://httpbin.org'

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def handle(self, req, resp):
        headers = dict(req.headers, Via='Falcon')
        for name in ('HOST', 'CONNECTION', 'REFERER'):
            headers.pop(name, None)

        request = requests.Request(req.method, self.UPSTREAM + req.path,
                                   data=req.bounded_stream.read(),
                                   headers=headers)
        prepared = request.prepare()
        from_upstream = self.session.send(prepared, stream=True)

        resp.content_type = from_upstream.headers.get('Content-Type',
                                                      falcon.MEDIA_HTML)
        resp.status = falcon.get_http_status(from_upstream.status_code)
        resp.stream = from_upstream.iter_content(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)


api = falcon.API()
api.add_sink(Proxy().handle)
```